# Flutter navigator doesn't show back button on App bar

Tags: flutter, button, navigator, appbar

I'm new to flutter and I'm Having a problem with Navigator , I don't know why it doesn't show back button on the next page (i want to show a back button on the next page app bar) when I use Navigator.push even though I have seen a lot of videos that show the opposite, maybe someone will have the answer here

here's the code I'm Using:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include your material route? and homePage appBar.

Comment: Please share your Next Page Code.

Comment: Your main page should also include a app bar

Answer (score 0):

In the appbar there is leading property...

In that leading property you can use any Widget. As your requirement you can use icon Widget to navigate

Answer (score 0):

You have to code the back button in "HomePage" class. In Flutter, when you navigate from page A to page B, the page B will be above page B, something like a stack, but page A and B have to be build on their owns.

A solution that might resolve your problem is to use this code in "HomePage"

```
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
                 child: Text('Back Button'),
                 onPressed: (){
                   Navigator.pop();
                   },
                ),
          ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => CardScreen() ));`

Make sure you are using `Navigator.push` instead of `Navigator.pushReplacement`